# Ansible with Concourse

Tags: ansible, concourse, concourse-pipeline

I am trying to run ansible playbooks within Concourse for remote hosts, however i cannot do that. Below are my steps:-

Concourse Yaml File:-

```
---
resource_types:
- name: ansible-playbook
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: troykinsella/concourse-ansible-playbook-resource
    tag: latest

resources:
- name: ansible
  type: ansible-playbook
  source:
    debug: true
    user: cloud_user
    ssh_private_key: ((ssh-key))
    verbose: vvv

- name: source-code
  type: git
  source:
    uri: ((git-repo))
    branch: master
    private_key: ((ssh-key))

jobs:
  - name: ansible-concourse
    plan:
    - get: source-code # git resource
    - put: ansible
      params:
        check: true
        diff: true
        become: true
        become_user: root
        inventory: inventory/hosts
        playbook: site.yml
        path: source-code
```

### Host File:-

```
[test]
localhost
```

### Inside the Container:-

I intercepted the container and i can ssh to any IP inside, however i am not able to make ssh-login.

### Ansible Playbook:-

```
---
- name: "Running Current Working Directory"
  hosts: test
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
     - name: "Current Working Directory"
       shell: pwd
       register: value

     - debug:
          msg: "The Current Working Directory {{value.stdout_lines}}"
```

### Output Coming in Concourse:-

```
ansible-playbook       -i inventory/hosts --private-key /tmp/ansible-playbook-resource-ssh-private-key   --user cloud_user   -vvv site.yml
ansible-playbook 2.9.0
  config file = /tmp/build/put/source-code/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) [GCC 8.3.0]
Using /tmp/build/put/source-code/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /tmp/build/put/source-code/inventory/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /tmp/build/put/source-code/inventory/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /tmp/build/put/source-code/inventory/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /tmp/build/put/source-code/inventory/hosts inventory source with ini plugin

PLAYBOOK: site.yml *************************************************************
1 plays in site.yml

PLAY [Running Current Working Directory] ***************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [Current Working Directory] ***********************************************
task path: /tmp/build/put/source-code/site.yml:7
Monday 18 November 2019  12:38:49 +0000 (0:00:00.084)       0:00:00.085 ******* 
<localhost> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: cloud_user
<localhost> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/tmp/ansible-playbook-resource-ssh-private-key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="cloud_user"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/dc52b3112c localhost '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~cloud_user && sleep 0'"'"''
<localhost> (255, b'', b'')
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ",
    "unreachable": true
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Monday 18 November 2019  12:38:49 +0000 (0:00:00.029)       0:00:00.114 ******* 
=============================================================================== 
Current Working Directory ----------------------------------------------- 0.03s
/tmp/build/put/source-code/site.yml:7 -----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost` is normally accessed through the [`local` connection plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/local.html) (unless you are trying to do something really special and you have configured access through ssh which does not seem to be the case from your above error message).

If you don't declare it in you inventory, `localhost` is implicit, uses the `local` connection and is not matched in the `all` group.

However, if you declare `localhost` explicitly in your inventory, the [default connection plugin becomes `ssh`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/ssh.html) and the `all` group matches this host too. You have to set the connection back to `local` yourself in that case.

You have two options to make your current test work:

1. Delete your inventory (or use one that does not explicitly declare `localhost`) and modify your playbook to target `localhost` directly => `hosts: localhost`
2. Keep your playbook as is and modify your inventory

   ```
   [test]
   localhost ansible_connection=local
   ```

Comment: Hey Hi, Thanks for your reply.. actually "localhost" is running if i declare that in under /etc/ansible/hosts via connection local method.

However my main goal is i have lot many servers which i need to run Ansible playbooks from the container. 
I can ssh to those systems through this concourse container, but i cannot make "ansible -m ping <group-name> 
The group name consists of multiple hosts like

[test]
1.1.1.1

Comment: In this case please edit your question and add the necessary info describing the real problem you are facing and trying to solve. Have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help section.